# Can I use factors from principal component analysis in correlation and regression analysis

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis

I used PCA to reduce outcome variables (cognitive function) from 5 to 2 factors.
Now can I use these two factors as dependent variables (representing cognitive function) in Spearman correlation matrix and in multiple regression analysis instead of using the original cognitive results?

Comment: You could do that: no rules against it. I'd recommend against calling these constructs factors when they are principal components. It's not clear that PCs would be better used in Spearman correlations when they are based on Pearson correlations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistically- there is no reason this should violate the assumptions of ordinary least squares or Spearman's correlation analysis.

Note, however, that interpretation might be slightly harder.